# Access 2010 update table field after form checkbox update

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-access-2010

I have an access 2010 database that I'm using to track the installation of equipment.

One table (tblSerial_Numbers) contains all equipment part numbers and serial numbers with a yes/no field type to indicate whether it's been installed or not

The second table (tblInstallation) tracks installation data i.e. date, location, part#, serial# etc...

I have a form based from tblInstallation for the end user to enter all the info needed to populate tblInstallation.

My problem is i want a checkbox on the same form to update the Installed field in tblSerial_numbers.

So for the checkbox i have an After Update event sub with the following code

```
Private Sub chkInstalled_AfterUpdate()
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblSerial_Numbers " & _
              "SET Installed = " & Nz(Me.chkInstalled) & _
              " WHERE Serial_Number = " & Nz(Me.cboSerNum)
End Sub
```

This is supposed to use the serial number specified in the form combo box (cboSerNum) to set "Installed" in tblSerial_Numbers to whatever the checkbox on the form is but it's not working. There are no errors either.

Any Help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Syntax error has been resolved, updating Installed field in tblSerial_Numbers still not working.

Comment: you have no space character before WHERE

Comment: ^ we have a winner DING DING DING

Comment: Thanks Nathan
That fixed the syntax error... But the update query isn't changing the state of the installed field in tblSerial_Numbers

Comment: is serial number of text type.

Comment: do you have a value for both me.chkInstalled and me.cboSerNum?

Comment: What is the bound column in cboSerNum? (Appears that its value was 242 when you selected 15030524 in the ComboBox). Also, not clear what you expecting to happen with Nz(Me.cboSerNum)

Comment: Nathan: in tblSerial_Numbers serial number is a number type. In tbl_Installation it's a lookup from tblSerial_Numbers so it's a number type in that table as well. BobSki: cboSerNum is required to have a value to create a record so yes. chkInstalled defaults to false but by checking it should change it to True so it always has a value as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this.

The heart of the problem was the SerNum field in tblInstallation. It was a lookup from tblSerial_numbers. The value in cboSerNum was the primary key (autonumber) for the record in tblSerial_Numbers, not the actual serial number of the device.

A Simple modification of the SQL query fixed the updating of the installation field in tblSerial_Numbers.

```
 Private Sub chkInstalled_AfterUpdate()
 CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblSerial_Numbers " & _
                   "SET Installed = " & Nz(Me.chkInstalled) & _
                   " WHERE ID = " & Nz(Me.cboSerNum)
 End Sub
```

This is my final code (just made it look more conventional)

```
 Private Sub chkInstalled_AfterUpdate()

 CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblSerial_Numbers " & _
                   "SET tblSerial_Numbers.[Installed] = " & Me.chkInstalled & _
                   " WHERE tblSerial_Numbers.[ID] = " & Me.cboSerNum & ";"

 End Sub
```